# Traverse two arrays in scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I am difficulty in understanding for loop traversal in Scala arrays.

I have two arrays and want to iterate over them with two pointers. One pointer starts from start of first array. Second pointer starts from end of second array.
I want to break from the loop when elements at two pointers satisfy a condition. At a time, i move one pointer of any loop. Can someone helps me how to approach these kind of problems.

**I m trying to solve the problem here**: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-arr-find-the-maximum-j-i-such-that-arrj-arri/

Given an array arr[], find the maximum j – i such that arr[j] > arr[i]

To solve this problem, we need to get two optimum indexes of arr[]: left index i and right index j.

1) For an element arr[i], we do not need to consider arr[i] for left index if there is an element smaller than arr[i] on left side of arr[i].

2) Similarly, if there is a greater element on right side of arr[j] then we do not need to consider this j for right index.

3)So we construct two auxiliary arrays LMin[] and RMax[] such that LMin[i] holds the smallest element on left side of arr[i] including arr[i], and RMax[j] holds the greatest element on right side of arr[j] including arr[j]. After constructing these two auxiliary arrays, we traverse both of these arrays from left to right.

4) While traversing LMin[] and RMa[] if we see that LMin[i] is greater than RMax[j], then we must move ahead in LMin[] (or do i++) because all elements on left of LMin[i] are greater than or equal to LMin[i]. Otherwise we must move ahead in RMax[j] to look for a greater j – i value.

```
val list =List(34, 8, 10, 3, 2, 80, 30, 33, 1)

  // Get all the minimum elements on left side for each index
  val minElementWithLeftIndexes = list.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(List((list(0), 0)), (list(0), 0))((l,r) => if(l._2._1 >= r._1) (l._1 :+r, r) else (l._1:+l._2, l._2))._1.drop(1)
  val maxElementWithRightIndexes = list.zipWithIndex.foldRight(List((list.last, list.length-1)), (list.last, list.length-1))((r,l) => if(l._2._1 <= r._1) (l._1 :+ r, r) else (l._1:+l._2, l._2))._1.drop(1)


  println(minElementWithLeftIndexes)
  println(maxElementWithRightIndexes)
 //Step 4 :  traverse on two lists to get the max value
```

**Not able to do step 4 with scala.**

Comment: Show some code.  You have to have at least tried something.  Give people here a starting point to provide feedback from.  It's not enough to say you can't do step 4, show what you have tried to do and what you want to do and where the gap is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 def f(l: List[Int]): Int = {

    l.map { x => l.map { y => (y, x)}}.flatten
    .filter(z => z._1 > z._2)
    .map { p => l.indexOf(p._1) - l.indexOf(p._2)}.max

  }


f: (l: List[Int])Int

scala> val l = List(9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 18, 0)
scala> f(l)
res0: Int = 8
scala> val l = List(34, 8, 10, 3, 2, 80, 30, 33, 1) 
scala> f(l)
res1: Int = 6
scala> val l = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
scala> f(l)
res2: Int = 5
scala> val l = List(6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
scala> f(l)
res3: Int = -1
```

Comment: it is a brute force approach to solve that problem. M looking for something like in algo which could helpful to understand scala list traversals